# Implementation of Graph Coloring Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-coloring

I came to know that graph colouring algorithms are NP-Complete problems. Still, I want to know whether any implementation is possible using heuristic approach or not, especially the **distinguishing graph colouring**? If possible then is there any suitable resource to learn about that ?

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in a somewhat [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792316/k-color-to-k-cnf-reduction-for-glucose-syrup/41110656#41110656):

Constraint solvers like [MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org) are able to solve a broad range of graph colouring problems.

This [MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org) example demonstrates colouring of the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph):

```
%  Petersen Graph
set of int: Colors = 1..3;
set of int: Nodes = 1..10;
set of int: Edges = 1..15;
array[Edges] of Nodes: aFrom = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4,  5, 6,  7, 7,  8, 6 ];
array[Edges] of Nodes: aTo   = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 9, 10, 9 ];

array[int] of string: colorName = [ "red", "green", "blue", "purple", "yellow", "brown", "black" ];

array[Nodes] of var Colors: nodeColor;

constraint
  forall(e in Edges) (
      nodeColor[aFrom[e]] != nodeColor[aTo[e]]
  );

solve satisfy;

output [ show(colorName[nodeColor[n]]) ++ "\n" | n in Nodes ];
```